# Cannot see xpath / html code / firepath for popup window

Tags: firefox, selenium, firebug, firepath

I am using firebug and firepath to see xpath or html code to use in my Selenium tests. But for one popup window I cannot see any html code or firepath... 
I also tried to right click to see xpath but I do not get any menu when right clicking on the popup.
It works fine on the rest of the wesite it is only this popup.. Is there any setting or something I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a java script alert. You will have to switch to the alert and then Use alert.accept() to mimic clicking on OK button of the alert.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I used following line in my Selenium code: driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
Thanks for quick reply!